# Get the administrators list of a Youtube channel with API 3

Tags: youtube-api

Is it possible to retrieve the administrators accounts of a Youtube channel with the API v3 Channels.list ?

Thanks a lot!﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channels.list will return a [Channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels) resource. If the Channel is linked to a G+ account, you can get more information from G+ via [contentDetails.googlePlusUserId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.googlePlusUserId).

Otherwise most of the information is in [snippet](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet) such as title, description and thumbnail image.

Also [more information on ChannelIds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/working_with_channel_ids#v3).